# Is there a way I can have an in between abstract state to avoid repeating same view template details?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this configuration for angular-ui-router:

```
var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWord = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w',
    template: "<div ui-view='wordData'></div><div ui-view='wordForms'></div>",
    url: '/:wordId',
};

var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordDelete = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.delete',
    views: {
        "wordData@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
            templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
                return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordData.html');
            }]
        },
        "wordForms@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
            templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
                return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordForms.html');
            }]
        }
    },
    url: '/delete',
};

var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordEdit = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.edit',
    views: {
        "wordData@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
            templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
                return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordData.html');
            }]
        },
        "wordForms@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
            templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
                return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordForms.html');
            }]
        }
    },
    url: '/edit',
};
```

I have an edit, delete and a new state that all share the same "views:".  Is there a way I could have some kind of abstract state containing just the views definition so I could avoid repeating "views" each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can create shared variable with view config:**

```
var sharedViewConfig = {
    "wordData@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
        templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
            return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordData.html');
        }]
    },
    "wordForms@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
        templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
            return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordForms.html');
        }]
    }
};

var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordDelete = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.delete',
    views: sharedViewConfig,
    url: '/delete',
};

var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordEdit = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.edit',
    views: sharedViewConfig,
    url: '/edit',
};
```

**Or you can create an abstract state:**

```
var abstractState = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.abstract',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        "wordData@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
            templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
                return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordData.html');
            }]
        },
        "wordForms@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
            templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
                return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordForms.html');
            }]
        }
    }
};

var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordDelete = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.delete',
    parent: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.abstract',
    url: '/delete',
};

var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordEdit = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.edit',
    parent: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.abstract',
    url: '/edit',
};
```

Comment: Thank you.  In the abstract view you have url: '/delete', I think that's a mistake. Can you have a look at ur answer. Also in the WordsDelete and WordsEdit can I just add "abstract" into the name to avoid the need for parent? Thanks very much

Comment: Definitely you're right, it's copy paste mistake :) `abstract: true` should be inserted into abstract state definition as well. I've made correction, now it should be ok.

Comment: To remove `parent` from state definition you can use proper state names i.e. if you have base state, which is abstract (or not) and its name is `base` then every state with name `base.something` will point `base` as its parent.

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
var viewDes= {
            "wordData@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
                templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
                    return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordData.html');
                }]
            },
            "wordForms@r.s.s.a.w.w": {
                templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
                    return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/wordForms.html');
                }]
            }
        };
var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordDelete = {
        name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.delete',
        views: viewDes,
        url: '/delete',
    };

    var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordEdit = {
        name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.edit',
        views: viewDes,
        url: '/edit',
    };
```